# OleDbException. No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, excel

```
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\a.xlsx" + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No'";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update [tablenameeee$] SET A1='15'", conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

i want to access a specific cell in excel , and change its value . but i got the exception

OleDbException. No value given for one or more required parameters.What is the solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use HDR=NO the column names are F1, F2 F3 etc......

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update [tablenameeee$] SET F1='15'", conn);
```

but I think you should specify a WHERE clause to delimit the affected rows.
Remeber, using OleDb you should not think in terms of Rows/Columns but in terms of Records.

As an alternative, if you know exactly the row/column to update you could use

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update [tablenameeee$A1:A1] SET F1='15'", conn);
```

Comment: how can we access directly which cell we want like A13 or H43

Comment: Added alternative syntax (tested with Excel 2003 - Jet.OleDb) but I think it works also with the newer ACE provider

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a where clause

```
Update [tablenameeee$] set [F1] = 15 where [F2] = 3
```

or if you want to access one specific cell, and you know which cell it is, then Steve's solution will fit like a glove to you.