# OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters. Update Query. Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel, oledbexception

Updating MS Excel. OldeDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters.
What is wrong in the below code,

```
private string _connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\\Workspace\\TestSet.xls;Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;READONLY=FALSE\"";

OpenConnection();
using (OleDbCommand objConfigCmdUpdate = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Config$] SET Enabled='1' WHERE TestSuite='CFTS'", ExlConn))
{
     objConfigCmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
     CloseConnection();
}
```

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `;` after `'CFTS'`?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this did not help. `using (OleDbCommand objConfigCmdUpdate = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Config$] SET Enabled='1' WHERE TestSuite='CFTS';", ExlConn))`

Comment: Nobody knows the solution to this issue? Someone help me. I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you use HDR=NO the column names are F1, F2 F3 etc......
so your query shlould be

```
"UPDATE [Config$] SET F1='1' WHERE F2='CFTS'"
```

for your ref [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284682/oledbexception-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters)

Comment: I dont to keep my code with respect to cell number, I want it to be column specific. Please suggest.

Comment: Dhaval, even this did not work. i tried the below command, `using (OleDbCommand objConfigCmdUpdate = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Config$] SET B4='1' WHERE A4='CFTS';", ExlConn))`